# Attach to existing container from command line

Tags: vscode-remote

I want to write a script, which run vscode in desired configuration:

- vscode is attached to running container, which can be identified by `docker ps | grep`
- select predefined path as folder

How it can be done?

Comment: Are you trying to open an interactive shell within a docker container that was started by VS Code?

Comment: No, I want to attach vscode to the running container, which was not started by the vscode